# How to listen for time change in React?

Tags: reactjs, date, time

I have a button which I want to remain disabled unless in a certain time window. Is there any way to do this in react?
I dont want to hard code it like

```
<button disabled={isCorrectTime()}>...
```

because if the user is already on the page, and the time changes to the correct time, the button will not get updated right? does anyone know of any solutions?

Comment: combination of `setInterval` and `useEffect`

Comment: You want your button to be enabled after some amount of time passed on the page ? or when a specific date ?

Answer (score 1):

You call **setTimeout** inside of the **useEffect** Hook . `useEffect` method runs  when it first renders then `setTimeout` block runs after some seconds (these seconds  passed into the second parameter of the setTimeout method) then you call the `clearTimeout()` to  cancel a timer .

**Example  :**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

function App() {
  const [disabled, setdisabled] = useState(true)
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setdisabled(false);
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> hello </h1>
      <button disabled= {disabled} > click me </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the time window a specific amount of time after a certain event? If so, you can use a timeout function to change a state variable that you can then use to control the disabled state of the button:

```
const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true)

setTimeout(() => {
  setIsDisabled(false);
}, 1000)
// set this time to whatever the desired length of time is
...
<button disabled={isDisabled} />
```

If this doesn't work, you might be able to use setInterval() to periodically check the current time, but I will need more information about what your goals are to know if that's the best way forward.

Comment: I mean for example the button should only be active on a certain date such as the 17th of September 2022 between 3pm and 4pm. Such as a link to an exam only available for that period of time. Sorry if my wording was unclear...

Comment: And so, you think there's a use case where it's not enough to just check on initialization, because a user might be sitting there with the window open waiting for the button to go live?

My concern about doing this based on the local time of the user is that there could theoretically be an error triggered if the user changes their date/time on their machine to trigger the button being active. Is handling this server-side an option?

Comment: Exactly, the user might log in and be waiting on the page 5 min before the actual time and then the button will not go live. How would you handle this server side?

Comment: What is your backend like? You could have a tiny endpoint (or a boolean on a different endpoint you are already using) that your frontend requests and doesn't let the button be active unless the server says it's active. The server could have a check for whether the time is valid by comparing the time of the request to acceptable time frame. On the fronted you can tell the user descriptively what time the button is available and tell them to refresh the page. If you absolutely need it to be automatic, you could have a timeout event that checks every min for whether button should be available.

Comment: The fancier version is to use a websocket

Comment: Oh, another thought. When the user comes to the page, you could have them check the difference between the current time and the start time, and set a timeout function for that length of time that will check for whether the button should be active. Then it makes a check, so as long as the user isn't modifying their time locally, they will have a good experience. If their device time doesn't match the server, you could then warn then that they are out of sync.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your various ideas! I like the last one between checking the current time and last one and then setting a timeout function. I think I will give that a try. Thanks!